# Mono for android - Android.OS and Android.Provider assemblies?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I'm using mono for android 4.6, trying to get device info. Samples that I've seen are below, but I'm not sure what reference to add in order to get these?

```
var device = Android.OS.Build.Device;  //type or namespace OS does not exist...(missing     assembly?)
var id = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId); //type or namespace 'Provider' does not exist..(missing assembly?)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Content;
using Android.App;

var device = Build.Device;
var id = Settings.Secure.GetString(Application.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but in case anyone is still having this problem, just append `global::` like:

```
var device = global::Android.OS.Build.Device;  //type or namespace OS does not exist...(missing     assembly?)
var id = global::Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, global::Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.OS.Build.Device

It is defined in `Mono.Android.dll`